# Accessing Mount from Azure Files in Cloud Service

Tags: c#, azure, azure-files

I successfully created and manually tested a share in Azure Files using instructions in [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2014/05/11/introducing-microsoft-azure-file-service.aspx).  However, my deployed cloud service can't create a mount from C# or access the mount (create or list files) if I create it by remoting into the role.

Comment: Have you tried the code at http://fabriccontroller.net/blog/posts/using-the-azure-file-service-in-your-cloud-services-web-roles-and-worker-role/?

Comment: Yeah, this worked.  I'll answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by calling map using the P/Invoke method explained [here](http://fabriccontroller.net/blog/posts/using-the-azure-file-service-in-your-cloud-services-web-roles-and-worker-role/).  The only trick was that I had to build the storage layer from [source](https://github.com/sandrinodimattia/RedDog) and updating the package references since it used a much older version of the Azure storage library.

If you're interested in what didn't work:

My first attempt was using a process and invoking 'cmd', but this failed completely I believe because of permissions, but I wasn't able to find out exactly why.  My next attempt was a startup script to mount the drive.  This resulted in a Disconnected drive that nothing could access even when I ran it with elevated permissions.

Comment: You don't need to install their entire repo. Just include everything from [this folder](https://github.com/sandrinodimattia/RedDog/tree/master/src/RedDog.Storage/Files) and you're good to go.